# Is that a good way to get random number?if not, why?

Tags: c++, random

So i tried to create a "real" random function, because rand wasn't random enough imo.

Do you think that it's a "good" way to get random numbers?if not, why?

```
int realrand() {
  double duration = 0;
  int i = 0;
  std::clock_t start;
  start = std::clock();

  while(duration < 0.001) {
    i++;
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  }

  int rand = i % 10;

  return rand;
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to come up with good pseudo-random generators. BTW, your function is as random as the clock variations are. So, for cryptographic purposes, it's probably not good enough. A quick test that you can do is to test its Shannon entropy and see how uniform your distribution is. Some good reading on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Comment: Better use `std::random_device` (true random numbers) or `std::mt19937` (pseudo random numbers) instead

Comment: If you think that the `rand()` provided by the **geniuses** that wrote your OS/C Library isn't enough (did you remembered to `srand(time(nullptr))` first?), then your only alternative is `/dev/random`.

Comment: @KemyLand: rand() is indeed no longer recommended, as it has quite a few design flaws. Luckily, c++11 introduced a portable replacement .

Comment: @MikeMB `std::random_device` is not guaranteed to produce genuine random numbers. It may, it may not, depending on the hardware.

Comment: @vsoftco: Right, but I think outside of uC-Programming, that is rather a theoretical problem.

Comment: @MikeMB Depending on what you want to do. If you're after implementing secure cryptographic protocols, then it makes a huge difference what kind of random numbers you use. But for "normal" applications, it's more than enough.

Comment: @MikeMB: If by "design flaws" you mean that it's not a real RNG (because it "generates the same sequence for the same seed"), then it actually was never intented to be one. It has always been a *pseudo-*random number generator.

Comment: @KernyLand: No, thats not at all what I meant. It just has been (at lest on some platforms) a very bad pseudo random number generator. If you are interested in the topic, I can recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Answer (score 7):

Two things.

1. Your random number generator is **really** slow.

   Computing the C++11 and C style rng 10000 times takes about 0.016 seconds on my laptop. Adding your code to the mix raises the cost to **10 seconds**!
2. The distribution of random numbers that you are creating sucks.

   ```
            You        C++11      rand()

   0:       9615       9007       9006
   1:       9143       9086       9008
   2:       8650       8929       8958
   3:       7907       9094       9114
   4:       7943       9022       9021
   5:       8098       8968       9005
   6:       8676       8991       8810
   7:       9970       8946       8903
   8:      10061       8908       9094
   9:       9938       9050       9082
   ```

   Let's show this data in a histogram. Note that the C and C++ implementations have about the same number of element in each bucket. On the other hand, your code is clearly preferring to output 0, 7, 8, or 9.

[image: Histogram of the above data]

Here's some code that I used to determine this:

```
#include <random>
#include <map>

int realrand() {
        double duration = 0;
        int i = 0;
        std::clock_t start;
        start = std::clock();

        while(duration < 0.001) {
                i++;
                duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        }

        int rand = i % 10;

        return rand;
}

int cpprand() {
        static std::random_device rd;
        static std::mt19937 rng(rd());
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 9);
        return dist(rng);
}

int crand() {
        static int once = []() {
                srand(time(NULL));
                return 0;
        }();

        return rand() % 10;
}

int main() {
        std::map<int, int> realrand_distribution;
        std::map<int, int> cpprand_distribution;
        std::map<int, int> crand_distribution;

        for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
                realrand_distribution[realrand()]++;
                cpprand_distribution[cpprand()]++;
                crand_distribution[crand()]++;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
                printf("%d: %10d %10d %10d\n", i, realrand_distribution[i], cpprand_distribution[i], crand_distribution[i]);
        }
}
```

And here's the code I used to generate the histogram:

```
import numpy
import pylab

x = numpy.arange(10)
width = 0.27

rects1 = pylab.bar(x+0*width, [9615, 9143, 8650, 7907, 7943, 8098, 8676, 9970, 10061, 9938], width, color='r')
rects2 = pylab.bar(x+1*width, [9007, 9086, 8929, 9094, 9022, 8968, 8991, 8946, 8908,  9050], width, color='b')
rects3 = pylab.bar(x+2*width, [9006, 9008, 8958, 9114, 9021, 9005, 8810, 8903, 9094,  9082], width, color='g')
pylab.legend([rects1, rects2, rects3], ["You", "C++", "C"])
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To get random numbers (better than `rand()`/`random()`/etc) you'll need to use a library. There are plenty available, and C++ makes it easy with some basic ones.

As noted above, `std::random_device` has issues. Unfortunately, it has *a lot more issues* than people realize.

If you want truly random numbers, you are currently better off using a system-specific method to get them: `/dev/urandom` on Mac and Linux and the CryptoAPI on Windows.

You can easily use the TRNG to initialize ("seed") a PRNG, like XORShift, Mersenne Twister, etc. If you need a CSPRNG, use a crypto library, but for everything else these will do.

*Don't* seed from the clock if you can avoid it. It is far less "random" than people assume. And whatever you do, ignore crap about using hashes with PIDs and the like.

Hope this helps.